# Solving an optimization problem where the decision variable is an unknown function to be solved for

Tags: functional-analysis, optimization, systems-of-equations

Apologies if this question is not well defined or if it lacks in mathematical understanding - I am still trying to improve my understanding and application of mathematics. Feel free to point me to relevant literature or books if you feel it is necessary.

My question is the following.

Suppose I have a transformation defined as follows:

$\phi : x \rightarrow y $ where $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $y \in \mathbb{R}^m$ and $m>n$

Also suppose that we know the time derivative of $x$ i.e. $\dot{x}$ then we can say by the chain rule:

$\dot{y} = J_{x}(y) \dot{x}$ where $J_{x}(y)$ is the Jacobian of y with respect to x. (Apologies for any abuse of notation)

Then I want my transformation to satisfy the following property:

$\dot{y} = J_{x}(y) \dot{x} = \lambda y$ where $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times m}$ is an unknown matrix of coefficients relating $\dot{y}$ to $y$.

In effect, I have a system of $m$ equations with $m$ unknown transformations as well as $m\cdot m$ unknown coefficients. We have an underdetermined system of equations. My approach was to try and reformulate this as an optimisation problem:

$\min_{\phi,\lambda}$   $ || J_{x}(y) \dot{x} - \lambda y|| $

However, I don't know if this approach is correct and, if it is, how such a problem could be solved, in particular, do methods exist to solve optimisation problems where the decision variable is itself a function and the goal is to find some function which minimises the objective function? Again apologies if this question is not well defined or explained correctly or even mathematically "correct". Please feel free to provide any pointers. Thanks

Comment: So $x(t)$ is a given function of time? But $\phi:\mathbb{R}^{n}\to\mathbb{R}^{m}$ is to be constructed? By that reading one obvious solution would be $\phi(x)=0$ for all $x$...

Comment: Hi Ali! Thanks for your comment. You're right, $\phi$ is to be constructed and $\phi(x)=0$ is indeed a trivial solution... I guess i'm more looking for a non-trivial solution to solving for  $\phi$ or more generally, if you know whether the approach mentioned above has an associated area of mathematics that I can read up further to try and see how to solve the problem?

Comment: [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Also note the system described by $\dot{y}=\lambda y$ can only display very simple behaviour.